# How to use Action scheduler when creating a WooCommerce plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, action-scheduler

I am creating a WooCommerce plugin on my WordPress site, and I want to create recurring actions. I followed step by step on the [usage](https://actionscheduler.org/usage/). What my current state is:

1. I installed the plugin on the Wordpress site
2. On my plugin, I created a `libraries` folder and dropped the `action-scheduler`

Afterwards, I use it on my plugin like so:

```
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/libraries/action-scheduler/action-scheduler.php' );

if ( false === as_next_scheduled_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_clone_order_weekly' ) ) {
    as_schedule_recurring_action( strtotime( '+5 minutes' ), 300, 'mutiara_woocommerce_order_clone', $order);
}

function mutiara_woocommerce_order_clone() {
    /* trigger clone */
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_clone_order', 'mutiara_woocommerce_order_clone', 20, 1 );
```

I thought this should be as straightforward as this. However, it shows an error right away: **"Call to undefined function as_enqueue_async_action()"**.

I also tried to wrap it like so:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'ActionScheduler', false ) || ! ActionScheduler::is_initialized() ) {
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/libraries/action-scheduler/action-scheduler.php' );
    ActionScheduler::init( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/libraries/action-scheduler/action-scheduler.php' );
}
```

I have been googling like crazy but unable to find the issue. Are there any steps I am missing?